# pattern matching for values in a list

Tags: r, list, pattern-matching

```
#create the new tables
mtcars2= mtcars
mtcars_ignore = mtcars * 25


mylist= list(  
  table_123 = mtcars, 
  table_234 = mtcars2, 
ignore_this_table = mtcars_ignore)
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can rbind only the values that are spelled similarly together.   For example normally to get everything together ... this way...

```
mydata = lapply(ls(pattern ='table_*'), get)
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to look just within my list using something like

```
mydata = lapply(list( mylist, pattern = 'table_*'), get)
```

Thanks

Comment: You may need grep i.e. `mylist[grep("table.*", names(mylist))]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
do.call(rbind,mylist[grepl("table_",names(mylist))])
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mylist[grepl("table_",names(mylist))])
```

The latter is much faster but depending on your actual use case it might not make a noticeable difference.